# Foreach listing Elements from list how chose a element before and after

Tags: development

If we foreach a object elements in loop, I want to add or delete before, or after some elements. How I can I do at the loop foreach. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for loop instead of foreach and use index to access the Items like:

```
for (int index=0; index < ItemsCollection.Count; index++)
{
    SPListItem item = ItemsCollection[index];
    item.Delete();
}
```

because if you delete an item from ForEach it will give an exception, since the collection is changed now!

Comment: And Maybe You know how to add the range to the ASP Calendar ?

Comment: Range? What do you mean by range?

Comment: The range between Date Sstat to Date Stop. Please help.